# Set field of mock class without setter

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I want to test this method with spock

```
public class MainService {   
  private final DLCRDDLPortType dlcrddlPortType;  
  public void startProcess(Application app) {          
        Holder<String> status = new Holder<>();     
        Holder<String> statusText = new Holder<>();          
        dlcrddlPortType.startProcess(app.getApplicationId(), status, statusText);     
        if (status.value.equals(FAIL_RESPONSE_STATUS)) {         
        throw new FailResponseException(String.format("Failed to get response with status %s and description %s", status.value, statusText.value));
```

}}

```
public final class Holder<T> implements Serializable {

    public T value; 

    public Holder() {
    }    

    public Holder(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**status.value** is null, I cant change it without setter and I cant create it with constructor, beacause I need mock. How can I fix it?

**Error:**
Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because "status.value" is null

**My test:**

```
private DLCRDDLPortType dlcrddlPortType
private MainService mainService
private Holder status
private Holder statusText

void setup() {
    status = GroovyMock()
    dlcrddlPortType = Mock()
    mainService= new MainService(dlcrddlPortType)
}

def "startProcess success"() {
    
    given:
    def appId = 171l     
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(status, "value", "SUCCESS")
    def app = Application.builder().applicationId(appId).build()
   
    when:
    mainService.startProcess(app)
    then:        
    1 * dlcrddlPortType.startProcess(appId, status, statusText)

}
```

Comment: Looks like to me that you need to mock `dlcrddlPortType` instead of `status`. Without sharing more of you class, ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can't really help you.

Comment: You need to set the Holder value or pass it into the constructor before checking if it's equal.
Holder<String> status = new Holder<>("value")


Right now when you run your test it is creating the Holder but with a null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from you partial example.
The important part is this:

```
            1 * dlcrddlPortType.startProcess(appId, _, _) >> { id, status, statusText ->
                status.value = "SUCCESS"
            }
```

With this you use the response generator to access the arguments, and set the value to the status holder.

Here is the slightly adapted example:

```
public class MainService {   
    private DLCRDDLPortType dlcrddlPortType;  
    public void startProcess(Application app) {          
        Holder<String> status = new Holder<>();     
        Holder<String> statusText = new Holder<>();          
        dlcrddlPortType.startProcess(app.getApplicationId(), status, statusText);     
        if (status.value.equals("FAIL_RESPONSE_STATUS")) {         
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Failed to get response with status %s and description %s", status.value, statusText.value));     
        }
    }
}

class Application {
    long applicationId
}

interface DLCRDDLPortType {
    void startProcess(long applicationId, Holder<String> status, Holder<String> statusText)
}


public final class Holder<T> implements Serializable {

    public T value; 

    public Holder() {
    }    

    public Holder(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class ASpec extends Specification {

    def "startProcess success"() {
        given:
        DLCRDDLPortType dlcrddlPortType = Mock()
        MainService mainService = new MainService(dlcrddlPortType: dlcrddlPortType)
        long appId = 171l     
        def app = new Application(applicationId: appId)

        when:
            mainService.startProcess(app)
        
        then:        
            1 * dlcrddlPortType.startProcess(appId, _, _) >> { id, status, statusText ->
                status.value = "SUCCESS"
            }
    }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?codez=eJyVVG1v2jAQ_p5fcYpUKZkYEp8mwRYJAdOQ6IaadF-RG1_AmnEy20C3iv8-J06IE6i6WrwkvrvnnnstDk-cpZByohTcEyZilEeWIrwAgGe-UEh2JBphvpo9zOerdS518qdAoDyVlPLmfdKoW8BjzigoTaReyzxFpYJpURgB0SwXQIoirDzUx2sevuWcovwca8nENioB9EHBFxB4amRREE7-wyjBZ_2KYde6F8ewQ9oQHW5RO9yXNAgHtY-B46tPimUQWOnwSPgBh_j7QLgK_K_T5WrzsIjXP77Hi02cTJPH2A_ddHjgHL2T-akKY8k5bgmPDSgunlMsSjqBjXqY5XJPtEEnjCMFnYOhDRJVkQuFcGJ612TzTgERFCiqVLIKxFz5TSyWrRuZvQn7AZ49-3v2PNs9boFfKiHPxbasdZu7UpsJjTIj6XVLWavr1rnGGdwu-ivXVX1K117dnRkThNdNX1skEbB9wXGPQiswU8AIZ3_JEy9puZ2dQJWPCXRuLUoQ1jGcq1TdUKitGz1bYVZn3fSrxfbaBF8PFeqfpdL7oNoqxQWmYBKCgpo4zQvL2qpV2hQz8N0CgDqk5b8fuM627IhifHl9Yz8YQvd5-isILwbuttk7z3ZoHWnQgxr3sVvMplOW1MCMPo14b9ZNZEZau3AaNuh019hChN7F8LRzQy2Pw_hqZbR8nMoYgJsDPoIPb-6gsuE35hNCFJlFweitDQQfow5wedyZNlH78eNstohjv6N4meR_jmrW_g)